# C# List inside class and namespace, accessing it from another class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Please excuse my little knowledge in C#, as this question may be very easy for some of you but I cannot get my head around it.

I have tried and searched many examples and tutorials, but all of them are only partial examples so I could not understand it properly.

**I have this class "FilesDataStruct":**

```
namespace MYPROJECT.FilesListData
{
    class FilesDataStruct
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

**And the class "FilesDataClass":**

```
namespace MYPROJECT.FilesListData
{
    class FilesDataClass
    {
        public List<FilesDataStruct> Files;

        public FilesDataClass()
        {
            Files = new List<FilesDataStruct>();
        }
    }
}
```

The namespace they are using is "**FilesListData**".

So I go to Class "**B**" in **MYPROJECT** and declare:

```
private FilesDataClass m_ListWorker;
```

And then add items to my list:

```
m_ListWorker = new FilesDataClass();

FilesDataStruct item = new FilesDataStruct();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    item.ID = i;
    item.Name = "Just_Testing";

    m_ListWorker.Files.Add(item);
}
```

Debugging this I can see the items are added properly.

Now I need to access this list in the "**Form1**" class ( or any other .. ):

So I declare again:

```
 private FilesDataClass m_ListWorker;
```

But reading the examples and tutorials I found, I have done this:

```
m_ListWorker = new FilesDataClass(); // this is weird, if I call the class again it's normal to be empty

for (int i = 0; i < m_ListWorker.Files.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m_ListWorker.Files[i].ID);
    Console.WriteLine(m_ListWorker.Files[i].Name);
}
```

And of course, nothing is there. I am guessing the problem is the constructor of "**FilesDataClass**" because each time you call "**new**" it will become a new empty class...

Please explain to me what in the world I am doing wrong, and how should I access my class to retrieve the items in ANY class that I want...

Comment: You are right, when calling `new FilesDataClass();` you are creating a new empty object of the class. You need to transfer your old m_ListWorker-object from Class B to Form1 somehow.

Comment: @Basti Yes, that it correct but how... this is why I asked the question.

Comment: That depends on your Class-Structure. If you initialize Class B in Form1 you can simply acess it via myClassBInstance.m_ListWorker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the existing class, not create a new instance of it.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    FilesDataClass m_ListWorker = null;

    public Form1(FilesDataClass f)
    {
        this.m_ListWorker = f;
    }
}

var newForm = new Form1(m_ListWorker);
```

---

You have a second issue too. That `for` loop will not work like you expect. You're simply adding the same instance of `FilesDataStruct` 10 times... in the end, you have 10 references that will all have the same values (the values you assigned in the last iteration of the loop).

```
m_ListWorker = new FilesDataClass();

FilesDataStruct item = new FilesDataStruct();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    item.ID = i;
    item.Name = "Just_Testing";

    m_ListWorker.Files.Add(item);
}
```

Instantiate the class inside the loop instead:

```
m_ListWorker = new FilesDataClass();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    FilesDataStruct item = new FilesDataStruct();
    item.ID = i;
    item.Name = "Just_Testing";

    m_ListWorker.Files.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction, this is becoming similar somehow with c++, but even so I cannot pass FilesDataClass f into Form1...

Comment: Well obviously, I need to do it in  Application.Run(new Form1()); too otherwise it will not compile...

Comment: I have solved the issue by setting "public static FilesDataClass m_ListWorker;" and then just accessing it. Your answer pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: And thanks for the for loop too, that is a mistake I made T_T

Answer (score 0):

You need to make B.m_ListWorker public (or better, a public property).Then you can access it as someInstanceOfB.ListWorker if it's an instance property or as B.ListWorker if it's static.